# Does long tail keyword rank impact the rank of short tail keywords too?

Tags: seo, google, keywords

We have an automobile website with product queries like:-

1) Audi A4

2) Audi A4 Images

3) Audi A4 Mileage

4) Audi A4 Finance

We rank decently well on the 1st two keywords (rank 1 to 5 for most of the queries) but our search engine rank for 3rd and 4th keyword mentioned above is not good enough (barely manage to come in page1).

Most of our keyword search is for "Audi A4". Only a few people search for long tail keywords like "Audi A4 Mileage" and "Audi A4 Finance".

Is there any co-relation b/w these rankings i.e. if we improve our long tail keyword rankings - would it improve our short tail rankings too?

Comment: This is a tricky question. Answer for this will depend on the kind of work done, content associated with it and how Google sees/awards your website. May be some more information on your website will help. Do those queries direct user to a blog page?

Comment: No. 2,3 and 4 are specialized pages i.e. Audi A4 Images will only have Images of the car, Audi A4 Mileage will only have mileage related details, Audi A4 Finance will have finance option related to that car. General "Audi A4" page will have all the above information i.e. Images, Mileage, Finance as different sections.

Comment: I see. Why don't you target all keywords to the root landing page using headers to signify importance of keywords and the product searches retrieve results based on '#' to direct to that section? I do not have any particular answer for this, let us see if anyone else can answer this query.

Comment: How can we indicate google to move to a particular section? What is better - moving user to particular section of the product page OR take user to a dedicated page?

Comment: For your particular niche, I cannot suggest anything as it might affect your ranking. On a general note, if the content is minimal and is being served on a page, we use <H1-H6> to distinguish the sections to let search engines and users know what they are browsing. If the content is more and provides more information compared to product page, holds more value, then I'd direct user to a dedicated page.

Comment: Not to confuse you further, since you seem to be a dealership, doesn't having information in the same product page, serve more value to the user? You can expect better conversion as well if the user is satisfied?

Comment: @idk you are right. I already have all this information in the product page. The problem is my product page is not ranking for the long tail keywords i.e. for keyword 2,3,4 mentioned above. I want a way by which i can rank higher for these keywords too. Plus, an answer if long tail keyword ranking would boost my short tail rankings too?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/90315/discussion-between-idk-and-maverick).

Answer (score -2):

It is all about keyword density of your web page and how you are using keywords. It will be reflected. Short term or long term is not the reason.
You need to work on optimization of key phrases according to their search volume.

Comment: Keyword density has never been an SEO metric worth anything.  In my experience using the keyword in the title, the heading, and the body once each is sufficient no matter how long the page.  Using keywords many times per page can lead to over optimization penalties.  Using keywords on many pages doesn't help rankings.